# Take a number and split it into indexed groups in a single dimensional array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a number like 12,345,678 and I'm trying to split it into an Array that's groups of 3. Such that if I have:

```
stack = 12345678
```

Then I could get the following Array:

```
overflow = [12,345,678]
```

I was thinking about using `Enumberable#each_slice` like another similar question asked here, but that creates a 2D array. So then I considered using `Array#flatten` but that wouldn't keep my numbers grouped properly.

Is there any nice way to do this, or is it going to be some nasty nested loop? Thx!

Comment: If you are on Rails, you can use `number_with_delimiter(12345678)                        # => 12,345,678`

Comment: Not on rails, just pure Ruby for this. Thx though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be efficient, but it works. You can build on/optimize it.

```
 stack.to_s.chars.reverse.each_slice(3).map {|s| s.reverse.join.to_i }.reverse
 # => [12, 345, 678]
```

Answer (score 2):

For pure Ruby way (Non-Rails):

```
number = 12345678
number.to_s.reverse.gsub(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/, '\\1,').reverse
#=> "12,345,678"
> number.to_s.reverse.gsub(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/, '\\1,').reverse.split(',').map(&:to_i)
#=> [12, 345, 678] # your expected output
```

If you want it in rails then there is very nice method **[number_with_delimiter](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper/number_with_delimiter)**

```
number_with_delimiter(12345678)
# => 12,345,678
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
def break_in_3s(num)
  return [0] if num.zero?
  a = []
  until num.zero?
    num, last = num.divmod(1000)
    a.unshift(last)
  end
  a
end

break_in_3s(12_345_678)
  #=> [12, 345, 678]
break_in_3s(2_345_678)
  #=> [2, 345, 678] 
break_in_3s(312_345_678)
  #=> [312, 345, 678]
```

I've assumed `num` is non-negative.

Aside: why don't we have:

```
class Array; alias >> unshift; end
```

so we could write:

```
a >> last
```

?